# Draw partial region of the webbrowser - using IViewObject.Draw()

Tags: c#, browser, screenshot, gdi

I'm using WebBrowser control to take screen shots of web pages and I'm able to get it working using IViewObject.Draw(). My question is that how can I draw partial region of the control. For example from (0px, 0px) to (200px, 200px).

Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution pretty much close to what I want. I ran JQuery scripts in the `WebBrowser` using `InvokeScript()` and hid all the controls in the page except what I want to take a screen shot. It worked well.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/html2image.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, possibly simpler depending on the scenario, is to simply clip the image to the bounds of the element.